# PHP+jQuery+Ajax+Json Printing out search results every keyclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, search, keyup

How do I make it so that every time (using keyup?) someone types in a letter into the search box it displays rows from MySQL DB that have the the same letters in them (uses the findUser function)? By default it shows all the users: [image]

and when I enter ".com" into the box above I need the table to reset and show only the rows with .com emails.

My current code (I don't know if I put the .keyup in the right place, but it seems to alert me at the right time):

index.php

```
<input id="search">
    <table border="1" BORDERCOLOR=black>
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>LastName</th><th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="theContent">

    </tbody>


    </table>



    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadUser(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.ajax.php'

        }).done(function(data){
            var HTML = '';
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(data['usersData'], function(key, val){
                HTML += getSingleUserLine(val);
            });

            $( '#search' ).keyup(function() {
                 alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
            });

            $('#theContent').html(HTML);

        });

    }

    function getSingleUserLine(data){
        if(data){
            var string = '';

            string = '<tr><td>'+data.fname+'</td><td>'+data.lname+'</td><td>'+data.email+'</td></tr>';

            return string;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){

        loadUser();

    });
    </script>
```

The main functions in user.class.php:

```
function loadUser($userID = false){
        global $DB;
        if($userID === false){
            $data = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
        }else{
            $data = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `users` where ID = '$userID' ");
            $data = $data[0];
        }
        return $data;
    }


    function findUser($phrase){
        global $DB;
        $result= $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$phrase%' OR lname LIKE '%$phrase%' OR email LIKE '%$phrase%'");
        return $result;
    }
```

and lastly users.ajax.php:

```
$return = array();

include('db.class.php');
include('user.class.php');

$DB = new DB (Cant give you this :( )
$USER = new User(); 




$data = $USER->loadUser();


$return['usersData'] = $data;

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: You could just [use an existing plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), of course.

Comment: I do not need auto complete of the text being written in, I need it to search with that text as keyword and then print it out everytime a symbol is typed in (keyup)

Comment: You're going to need to use Regex to match the HTML of your <td>s, and if found, show the .parent (<tr>) and hide all other <tr>s.

Comment: Check out jquery Datatables https://datatables.net/, particularly the Search functionality

Comment: Is there some way to do it without using additional plugins? just with what's provided? the functionality of those datatables look like exactly what I need.

Comment: You can implement your own solution, but why re-invent the wheel?  Plus, the DataTables plugins undergo stringent testing, including cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: use keyup combined with ajax and then use like in the php file

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be perfect for your requirement if you use jquery datatable plugin.It is easy to use and maintain. Go to  https://datatables.net/  and type any string in table that will fiter the table with match character

Comment: Again, is it possible to do without datatables plugin? Maybe there's a way to call the "findUser" function that I wrote in user.class.php every click?

Comment: Yes you can do it without plugin,sending ajax call with every typed character(i.e On keyup event) to server and get result.But whyn't an existing solution.Is it necessary to reinvent the whell???